# How do I remove object(s) from an array without leaving a hole in the array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

This may seem like a duplicate question, but the questions I have seen so far have not answered my question. For one of my homework assignments I had to write a `method` to remove any object from the `array` that contained an attribute that was passed in as a parameter. I needed to do this without leaving holes in the `array`, but there was able to be nulls at the end. I was able to do this with one loop as I shifted the last object in the `array` in place of the object that needed to be removed. But there was an error and I am not able to get clarification from my lecturer as to why. Code is below:

```
public void removeAllLine(int line){
  for (int i = 0; i < _noOfBuses; i++) {
      if (line == _buses[i].getLineNum()) // checking to see if number passed in is equal to the line number in the specific element of the array 
        { _buses[i] = _buses[--_noOfBuses]; }
        } /* shifting the last object in the array to the place of the removed object */
    }
```

I cannot use arrayList and one of the lecturers said it can and should be done via one loop. The order of the objects in the array is not important.

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Without even looking at logic, the error could be that you have 3 left (opening) brackets and 4 right (closing) brackets.

Comment: @DanielSiebert it's probably a class end bracket.

Comment: @Johnny I'm not sure, the line " {_buses[i] = ... } really doesn't look right to me.

Comment: @DanielSiebert will remove the extra bracket.

Comment: @Hackerdarshi no I cannot use Vector because I do not think I have learned that yet.
@Eran this is the error I received back from the lecturer: `Comment - Error: removeAllLine(20) test expected=3 : actual=4   -2 points`

Comment: Are you supposed to keep the elements in their original order?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan my understanding is that the important thing was no holes, but order did not matter at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you made is, that you skip the last buses, since you put it in the place, you already checked, you might change the line

```
if (line == _buses[i].getLineNum()) // checking to see if number passed in is equal to the line number in the specific element of the array 
        { _buses[i] = _buses[--_noOfBuses]; }
```

to

```
if (line == _buses[i].getLineNum()){ // checking to see if number passed in is equal to the line number in the specific element of the array 
     _buses[i] = _buses[--_noOfBuses];
     _buses[_noOfBuses]=null; //deletes last element
     i--;
}
```

so you will check the last one again. Also you have now 2 copies of the last ones, so you should "delete" the last element, you copied (see comment).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Is it possible to decrement and increment the i in the same loop?

Comment: Yes sure. Just take care, that you dont create an infinite loop.

Comment: How do I make sure there is no infinite loop?

Comment: Also, how do I make the last one, the one that is being copied, null?

Comment: In this case, you won't create one, since you either change the upper bound or the counter. It can happen, if you write something like `for(i=0; i<1; i++){i--;}` I inserted the deletion at the proper spot.

Answer (score 1):

Making the following assumptions:

- <s>You want to maintain the order of buses</s>
- There are no gaps (i.e. [bus][null][bus])
- <s>There are not multiple buses with the same 'LineNum'</s>

In your code, what you are doing is simply swapping the values of the buses, which the second can be null... and would break my second assumption. Instead, I think you wanted to *shift* instead of swap. This means you will maintain the order and **remove** from the list, which you aren't actually doing... you're just putting it at the end of your list.

To do the shift that I describe you will need an inner loop that runs once you find the values to do the additional logic.

```
public void removeAllLine(int line){
    for(int i = 0; i < _busesCount; i++){
        if(line == _buses[i].getLineNum()){
            // Shift the remaining elements down
            for(int j = i; j + 1 < _busesCount; j++){
                _buses[j] = _buses[j + 1];
            }
            // Ensure we don't duplicate the last element after the shift
            _buses[_busesCount - 1] = null;
            _busesCount--;
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:** I have updated my answer, which now handles duplicates, opposed to assuming that the elements are unique. I am sure there is a more efficient (performance) solution that involves swapping instead of shifting, but the code becomes more complicated. I still like my approach because it still works if assumption 1 was true. If assumption 3 was true then we would have have a break under

```
_bussesCount--;
```

Comment: I think he wants to remove all elements with the attribute, so you should change the `break;` to `i--; _busesCount--;` and this would be a fine solution which keeps the order.

Comment: @ctst i'm not sure about that. Directly from his question: "For one of my homework assignments I had to write a method to remove an object from the array that contained an attribute that was passed in as a parameter". If you're right about having multiple instances, then I agree.

Comment: @Daniel Siebert order is not important here and there could be more multiples bus lines with the same 'LineNum'.

Comment: I should have written any objects instead of an object.

Comment: @user1454994 please update the question with the details and I will update my answer

Comment: You still forgot about the issue with `i--;` :-) (the deleted position won't be considered again).

Comment: @Daniel Siebert, I updated my question to say that assumption three is incorrect. But even so, if there were multiple objects that needed to be removed, why would I need a break statement there? And I am not sure how assigning the last element in the array in place of the element that needs to be removed is swapping.

Comment: @user1454994 I was just actually giving examples of how I would solve the problem if those assumptions were true. So the break would save you a few iterations of the loop only if we knew there was only unique bus line for each of your elements. Doing this with a swap and multiple of the same isn't easy, and even harder to try and understand - so I wouldn't suggest it.